# String to Date Object

Tags: javascript, time

Is there a way I can convert "2013, 7, 7, 17" to a date object, 2013, 7, 7, 17?

I have tried new Date(), but I get error `date:Invalid Date`

These dates will be used to graph data.

Comment: you can't do it with JSON.parse() as it is not json. If you want to change it then concate the string.

Comment: If you just want to remove the `"`, see [**`this`**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/78Lmzqgr/) demo.

Comment: You want to parse a string into an array?

Comment: @connexo I updated the post

Comment: What date format you want? YYYY, MM, DD? There is one number too much.

Comment: @connexo year, month, day and hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, please invest a little more effort into precisely describing your problem.

You can go like this:

```
var dateString = "2013, 7, 7, 17";
var d = dateString.split(",");
var realDate = new Date(d[0], d[1]-1, d[2], d[3]); // month is 0-based, so 7 is August
```